# jMeter "view results in table"

Tags: sql, logging, jmeter

I use jMeter and "View result in table" listener.
My test plans contains few SQL select queries, which I have grouped in "Transaction controller"

As report in  "View result in table" logs I can see something like that:

......

```
20:25:58,55,SELECT 27,200,OK,Testerzy OS 1-10,text,true,50,0
20:25:58,106,SELECT 28,200,OK,Testerzy OS 1-10,text,true,23,0
20:25:58,92,SELECT 29,200,OK,Testerzy OS 1-10,text,true,35,0
20:25:00,3129,Transaction Controller 2001,200,"Number of samples in transaction : 32, number of failing samples : 0",Testerzy OS 1-1,,true,10267,247
```

How can I change it to see only:

```
20:25:00,3129,Transaction Controller 2001,200,"Number of samples in transaction : 32, number of failing samples : 0",Testerzy OS 1-1,,true,10267,247
```

in logs file ?

Answer (score 2):

Please select below option in transaction Controller

[image]